# MovePrevious deleting text from populated label

Tags: vb.net

I am building a simple program around an Access database using VB.net, and I'm having an issue.

As shown in the screen capture provided, I have a Next Record and Previous record button to navigate the database's information on this particular tab control. The Next Record button works fine (though I would like to make it loop back to the start once Next Record is clicked on the last record), but the Previous Record button erases both name labels while still displaying the band name, country, instrument, and ID number. The code for the Previous Record button is:

`Private Sub btnPrev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
        Me.MusiciansBindingSource.MovePrevious()
    End Sub`

I have tried repopulating the data with `Me.MusiciansTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MusiciansDataSet.Musicians)` before the record moves back, but that didn't work. I'm at a loss for what else to try. Here is the aforementioned screen capture.

[image: Missing label text]

I can provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `If MusiciansBindingSource.Position > 0 then MusiciansBindingSource.MovePrevious() else MusiciansBindingSource.MoveLast()`. The opposite for `MoveNext()`. These methods don't delete anything.

Comment: That worked on making the records loop around, but the two name labels are still going blank once you go back to a previous record that has been viewed already. There is nothing in my code that should conflict with anything to cause this issue.